# pyinstaller and pandas(multiple hooks missing)

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

Earlier I had this hook missing `pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime`. I looked 
at this 
article [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2978) and fixes this.

Now when i created the .exe file using pyinstaller, it shows another hook missing `pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype`.
I have already added the 1st missing hook to hiddenimports created under hook-pandas.py.

So, how can I add two missing hooks to hook-pandas.py or suggest otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by doing the following:

i) I edited the $.spec file which was in scripts folder.
inside
`a = Analysis([.....hiddenimports=[ ].....])`

ii) I added missing modules in hiddenimports with contents:
`hiddenimports=['pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype', 'pandas._libs.skiplist']`
(I also had `'pandas._libs.skiplist'` module missing so i added it too)
Save it

iii)Run `pyinstaller my_app.spec`.